# Are child component input properties resolved before ngOnInit?

Tags: angular

I have a parent component that is creating three identical child components. The children have an input that corresponds to some autocomplete data formatted as an array. However when I attempt to populate the array in the parent's ngOnInit and then pass it to one of the children, the child receives undefined as the array instance. If I try passing null as the input the same thing happens.

I'm just wondering if the lifecycle is causing this and I should use ngAfterInit or something else instead?

Parent component

```
<app-alert-chip-list [autocompleteData]="targetGroupAutocomplete"></app-alert-chip-list>
<app-alert-chip-list [fArray]="alertContacts" [autocompleteData]="null"></app-alert-chip-list>
...

ngOnInit() {
    this.targetGroupAutocomplete = ['This is the first autocomplete', 'This is a second sentence that is a longer sentence than the first autocomplete', 'This'];
  }
```

Child component

```
@Input() fArray: FormArray;
  @Input() autocompleteData: string[];

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    if(this.autocompleteData && this.autocompleteData.length != 0) {
      this.usesAutocomplete = true;
    }
    console.log("AC:", this.autocompleteData); //Ends up printing undefined
  }
```

Comment: Can you please reproduce it in stackblitz?

Comment: change from ngOnInit to ngAfterViewInit inside the child component

Answer (score 1):

I suggest another approach: use "setters" in your input:

```
private _autoCompleteData: string[]; //declare a a private variable

@Input() fArray: FormArray;

@Input() set autocompleteData(value) {
  this._autoCompleteData = value; //equal the variable

  if(value && value.length != 0) { //another code that it's relationated with autoCompleteData
    this.usesAutocomplete = true;
    console.log("AC:", this.autocompleteData); //Ends up printing undefined
  }
}

get autoCompleteData() {
  return this._autoCompleteData
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to watch your child inputs changes through ngOnchanges

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    for (let propName in changes) {
      let change = changes[propName];
      if (propName === "YOUR_INPUT_NAME") {
        this.YOUR_INPUT_NAME = (change.currentValue);
          // you can add whatever logic that to be executed. depend on which input is changed 
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Why do I need to do something as complex as this just for passing an input to a child component? I've done the exact same thing in a different component and it's working with no issues.

Comment: Cause your input value has been changed and the child component will only deal with the initial value in the first run

Comment: It hasn't changed though, it's been set in the ngOnInit and then passed to the first child?

Comment: No it is changed, from undefined to the new value in the parent onInit life cycle

Comment: @TamerHussien, I think it's a better aproach using "setters" in `@Input` (for me it's more "natural")

Comment: you don't need such mechanism at all : the value of each @Input is automatically updated if it's changed in the parent component without having to use the onChanges lifecycle hook. It's the key principle of a smart/dumb component architecture.

Comment: @Eliseo if it is only one input and you want to detect it's changes yes setter is more suitable but for more than one Input and you want to detect them it more better to use ngOnchanges

Comment: @GérômeGrignon  only the inital value will be used here if you didn't use setter or ngOnchanges and if you will change the inputs values through api subscribe or something else it will not be reflected in the child component

Comment: @TamerHussien, the "parameter itselft" Angular reflect the new value (the problem is when you need make some action more), in the example give value to usesAutocomplete

Comment: @Eliseo you can add your logic in the onChange life cycle and you can limit it to be executed when specific input is changed

Comment: @TamerHussien if you change the value with anything inside the parent, it'll be updated in the child. If you change the input value within the child, the only case where it won't be updated is having a OnPush change detection strategy.